# Using multiple PipedInputStreams & PipedOutputStreams

Tags: java, inputstream, pipe, outputstream

I am using PipedInputStream & PipedOuputStream to write a large XML document to an OutputStream which then needs to be consumed from an InputStream.

I have this working for the simple one stream out/one stream in scenario, but I have a need to loop through a very large set of products and write two slightly different items for each product, streaming to two different files.

The following psuedocode shows the approach I'm trying to take to implement this requirement:

```
PipedInputStream is1 = new PipedInputStream();
PipedInputStream is2 = new PipedInputStream();

PipedOutputStream os1 = new PipedOutputStream(is1);
PipedOutputStream os2 = new PipedOutputStream(is2);

new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter1 = createXMLStreamWriter(os1);
            // Write header content with xmlWriter1

            XMLStreamWriter xmlWriter2 = createXMLStreamWriter(os2);
            // Write header content with xmlWriter2

            for (Product product : someProducts) {
                // marshal item for product to xmlWriter1
                // marshal item for product to xmlWriter2
            }

            // Writer footer, close & flush with xmlWriter1
            // Writer footer, close & flush with xmlWriter2
        } finally {
            // Additional try/catch excluded for simplicity
            os1.close();
            os2.close();
        }
    }
}).start();

// Consume is1
// Consume is2
```

As mentioned, this works fine for one PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream, but with two as shown above, it only seems to work when writing content below a certain size. When the content goes above a certain size, it hangs when writing the closing elements of the second XML document.

Any ideas why this would happen, and what the resolution might be? Is the above approach even feasible?

Comment: could be resource thrashing.  Do you need to do the two files in parallel?  Can they not be processed sequentially?

Comment: The reason for the two in parallel is so that I can retrieve products from the db in pages, looping through the product list just once to generate the files. There's a possible future requirement for > 2 files to be produced, each with a lot of common product data and only small variances, and this just seemed like the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I take "retrieve products from the db in pages" to mean you're batching your db retrieval?  If so, good.  Have you tried flushing the xmlstreamwriters every so often, e.g. after each db batch?

Comment: Thanks - good suggestion. Unfortunately doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to wait for it to hang, pause the stuck thread, and see what it's waiting for.  Keep an eye also on CPU and head usage (the latter can be done in jconsole) and see what your resource utilization is at.

Comment: Err, that should read "heap usage" not "head usage"